# Cannot run "specific test" in Quarkus. Always it runs all the tests

Tags: testing, quarkus

In the Quarkus guides there is a point to pass specific tests based on profiles. I have already run through [this guide](https://es.quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#running-specific-tests) a few times. And I can't get it to run only the tests labeled with a profile. It always runs them all.

I use MySQLContainer to pass some specific tests. And H2 for the others. On local I want to run them all, but on a remote pipeline I don't want to run testContainers.

The test for H2 are annotated with:

```java
@QuarkusTestResource(H2DatabaseTestResource.class)
@QuarkusTest
@TestProfile(Profiles.QuarkusTag.class)
```

And the test for MySQLContainer with:

```java
@QuarkusTestResource(MySQLDatabaseTestResource.class)
@QuarkusTest
@TestProfile(Profiles.ContainerTag.class)
```

I have a new class called **Profiles**

```java
public class Profiles {

    public static class QuarkusTag implements QuarkusTestProfile {
        @Override
        public Set<String> tags() {
            return Collections.singleton("H2");
        }
    }

    public static class ContainerTag implements QuarkusTestProfile {
        @Override
        public Set<String> tags() {
            return Collections.singleton("MySQLContainer");
        }
    }
}
```

And I write in `application.properties`

```
quarkus.test.profile.tags=MySQLContainer
```

And the code of **MySQLDatabaseTestResource** is:

```java
public class MySQLDatabaseTestResource implements QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager{

    private static MySQLContainer<?> MYSQL_CONTAINER = new MySQLContainer<>("mysql:latest")
            .withDatabaseName("test")
            .withUsername("xxx")
            .withPassword("xxx")
            .withExposedPorts(3306);

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> start() {

        MYSQL_CONTAINER.start();
        System.out.println("[INFO] MySQL database started in TCP server mode; server status: "  + MYSQL_CONTAINER.getJdbcUrl());

        Map<String, String> conf = new HashMap<>();
        conf.put("quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url", MYSQL_CONTAINER.getJdbcUrl());
        return conf;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (MYSQL_CONTAINER != null) {
            MYSQL_CONTAINER.stop();
            System.out.println("[INFO] MySQL database was shut down; server status: " + MYSQL_CONTAINER.isHealthy());
            MYSQL_CONTAINER = null;
        }
    }
}
```

When I write `mvn test`, it always runs all the test, even if I hace configurated the profile in the `application.properties` file.

However, when I run `mvn test -Dquarkus.test.profile.tags=MySQLContainer` it does work fine

What am I doing wrong?

[quarkus](/questions/tagged/quarkus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did nothing wrong. According to [this issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/35693)

> this value is only read from the system properties directly

For now, only `mvn test -Dquarkus.test.profile.tags=MySQLContainer` should work as it does.